# Count Preceding Siblings Table

Tags: xml, xpath

My XML structure looks like ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manual>
  <div>
    <graphic>
    </graphic>
    <graphic>
    </graphic>
  </div>
  <div>
    <graphic>
    </graphic>
    <graphic>
    </graphic>
    <generic>
    </generic>
 </div>
</manual>
```

Here my context node is `manual/div/graphic`. So when I use it from second division's first graphic, I want to show `2.1`.

Similarly from first `manual/div/graphic` node, it should show `1.1`.

The syntax is `<Division No. ><Num of Graphic Element inside Div>`.

I have framed logic for `<Division No>` and bit stuck with `<Num of Graphic Element inside Div>`. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
concat(count(../preceding-sibling::div) + 1, '.', count(preceding-sibling::graphic) + 1)
```

which will calculate the answer by determining how many preceding `div`s there are for the parent node, and how many preceding `graphic`s there are for the context node, and concatenating them together, separated by a period.

Comment: Thanks Keith , One quick question , is it possible to get all graphics of previous ancestor . i.e  when div/graphic of second Division is used , I wanted to return 2 graphics under First Division (First ancestor.)